# Google oAuth for backend through frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, oauth, google-oauth

Question: 
First, this is a difficult question for me to word, so sorry in advance... How can I validate my user through the front end using a valid OAuth token from the backend?

Explanation:
I have successfully implement google oAuth through our backend (ruby on rails with devise and google oAuth). Our front end application is built on WordPress. Boss wants to utilize the google oAuth through our front end application.

My Attempt:
Currently, I just have the front end redirect to the backend and it logs in to the backend. Where I am getting stuck is when I try to redirect to the front end application with credentials. I believe I am going to need to create a page on the wordpress app that will pretty much send an API to the backend to validate the request and then login.

I don't need a complete answer, more so guidance on how to resolve this securely.
Thanks SO

Answer (score 2):

JUST TRYING TO HELP- since i'm also experiencing a similar issue :D

The only thing I've found which might work is if you basically open the link with an anchor tag from the frontend instead of using axios or something similar. This way you can register the user but the tricky thing left to do is to somehow return that token.